# Viewport Text Size (vh, vw) Relative to Parent Container Instead of Window?

Tags: css

What I'm trying to accomplish is making a box where the text will be exactly the same size relative to the box, no matter by what method the box is resized.

In the code below, the "small_box" has the intended behavior, it follows the bigger box no matter what, but the text does not. I would need the text to follow it as well.

Here's the codepen https://codepen.io/anon/pen/RxKowB (try resizing the window to see the behavior)

```css
.box {
  border: 2px solid black;
}

.box__frame {
  width: 100%;
  padding-bottom: 120%;
  position: relative;
}

.box__small_box {
  position: absolute;
  top: 4%;
  left: 10%;
  width: 20%;
  padding-bottom: 10%;
}

.box__text {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%);
  transform: translateX(-50%);
}

.box__text_name {
  font-size: 8vw;
  top: 60%;
}

.box__text_body {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 5vw;
  top: 70%;
}
```

```html
<div style="max-width:800px;">
  <div class="box box__frame">
    <div class="box box__small_box"></div>
    <div class="box__text box__text_name">
      This is the title
    </div>
    <div class="box__text box__text_body">
      This is the long description. This is the long description. This is the long description.
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Why do you even have this class? Why is the text placed absolute ?

.box__text {
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%);
    transform: translateX(-50%);
  }

Comment: You can alternatively remove the inline style -> max-width in your HTML.

Comment: It needs to be absolute for reasons that are not portrayed here. This is a simplified example. If you have a solution for my question that requires removing the absolute, that might be a possibility. The inline style is there also for this example purpose. Without it, the box is the same size as the screen and vh and vw work. But my box will not always be full width. Note that I'm not trying to make a responsive website, I'm trying to make something that is fixed but also scales while keeping proportions.

Answer (score 0):

The solution may not be possible using CSS alone if the text is floating.

These libraries maybe of some help.

http://simplefocus.com/flowtype/

http://fittextjs.com/

Comment: It might be possible to remove the floating, what's the solution that would require me to remove it?